# Raster calculator for RUSLE (six factors)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.

I have tried many time to estimate soil loss by RUSEL, using R, K, LS, C and P factors. However raster calculator failed. The message suggest was here:

1. Error 000539
   2)File "expression", line 1, in module
2. file "string" line 5, in rcexec
   when i try to running the raster
3. combine all factors (R, K, LS, C and P) factors failed but a combination of factor R, K and LS working again a combination of C nd P factors working.
   what is the reason
   To tried to overcome this issue as following
4. By changing the  coordinate and location of file, but still fail,
   what is the problem

Comment: Can you show your input to Raster Calculator as well as the exact error message? It's hard to troubleshoot the problem if you can't see the exact input and output.